# Excel adding another variable to a IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, statements

I have the current formula that I am using and I need to add another variable to it.

```
=IF(A6="In Process",IF(TODAY()>N6,"Past Due",""),"")
```

I need to add "Not Started" to the "In Process" IF statement. I have tried several different ways and keep running into a road block and need help.

Comment: you need to clarify a little bit.  If something=true then do 'this', else 'that'. you can add a nested if inside the 'this' or the 'that' quite easily. based on what you have asked, you can do its a couple different ways and it isn't clear on what the conditions are.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the formula to so the same with "Not started" as "In Process"? If so try using OR, i.e.

`=IF(AND(OR(A6={"In Process","Not Started"}),TODAY()>N6),"Past Due","")`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!